# libav audio latency / cannot set audio_buffer_size

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

For an audio/video capturing tool we open live capture devices with the following code:

```
AVFormatContext* ic = nullptr;
const AVInputFormat *iformat = av_find_input_format("dshow");
AVDictionary *options = nullptr;
av_dict_set(&options, "audio_buffer_size", "50", 0);
av_dict_set(&options, "framerate", "30", 0);
av_dict_set(&options, "video_size", "640x360", 0);
av_dict_set(&options, "sample_rate", "48000", 0);
auto err = avformat_open_input(&ic, "video=Integrated Camera:audio=Microphone Array", iformat, &options);
```

**Audio sample_rate, framerate and video_size are correctly set**, but the audio_buffer_size setting is ignored, resulting in a strong audio delay. Is there something wrong in the way we set it? The [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#toc-Options-5) says, the value is given in milliseconds (not sample size):

If audio_buffer_size cannot be set for all devices, is there an api call where we can get the currently active audio buffer size, so we can correct this elsewhere?

Comment: Does the log have a line saying "unable to set audio buffer size"?

Comment: @Gyan unfortunately not, i found this log error also in dshow.c but did not find in output.

[dshow @ ..] Selecting pin Capture on video
[dshow @ ..] not reusing previous graph capture filter @device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{6276A00C-C9ED-4177-BA77-8F02C4049A45} != @device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_13d3&pid_5279&mi_00#7&f7bbb15&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global
[dshow @ ..] Selecting pin Capture on audio only
[dshow @ ..] passing through packet of type audio size    38400 [..]
[dshow @ ..] All info found